# yii SEO редирект

Tags: yii, seo, редирект

Есть yii 1.1.
После правки алиасов страниц в базе, возникла необходимость сделать 301 редирект со старых урлов на новые. Когда в классе `CApplicationComponent`, в методе `init()` ставлю для теста простую проверку на `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` с последующим редиректом на корректный урл - сразу же отправляет на 404 страницу. Есть мысли, как это грамотно сделать?

Comment: больше конкретики, как обрабатываются запросы, что еще сделано, ну и т.д.

Comment: Да ну я даже не знаю, какой информации больше дать. Вношу правки на сайте на уіі, но не могу настроить редирект. Проблема в том, что на страницах, алиасы которых есть в бд, костыльный редирект работает, но как только дело доходит до несуществующего алиаса - сразу загружается страница 404 с тем же урлом в адресной строке.

Comment: Ну, для начала кусочек кода, как происходит редирект. Как бы тут нет тех кто может представить, что у тебя там написано.

Answer (score 1):

Если изменились только алиасы то сделайте редирект в самом контроллере. Который отвечает за обработку запросов этих страниц. То есть до каких либо действий проверьте есть ли в базе страница имеющая старый алиас, совпадающий с запрашиваемым. Если есть - зная её новый алиас - делайте редирект. При запросе страниц с новым алиасом редиректа не будет, потому что страницы с таким именем нет.

Если же поменялись пути в корне то это легко делается на уровне urlManager + новый контроллер специально сделанный для редиректов. Если приведете примеры адресов старых и новых страниц распишу подробнее с примером.